# Paging goes back to 1st page when changing "questions per page" option

Tags: feature-request, pagination

Stack Overflow has 2147 pages with new questions.

If am on the 2147th page and the "questions per page" is set to 30, it's shows two questions (This SO first questions). But when I change the "per page" from  30 to 50, then it's goes to the 1st page. Is this wrong? Actually here we need to be shown the last 50 questions on the last (2147th) page.

I don't know if this is a bug, but you can take this as a feature request.

Comment: I'd call this more of a feature request than a bug, but this would be useful.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy ! And please edit my question for understand for all peoples. I think my English may be bad :p   oops